# Tabular forms in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to build a tabular form in rails 3+.

Example Link : http://blog.theapexfreelancer.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/tabular-form.png

Is there any gem i can use to accomplish this ?

## Requirements :

1. Once the form is filled and data submitted into the DB. The user must be able to
   update the data in the form in-place. (the form fields doubles as read and write)
   [Require Ajax]
2. Multiple rows for data entry/update .

## MY investigation :

Gems :

- nested_form
- twitter_bootstrap_form_for
- formtastic-bootstrap

The documentation does not include Tabular forms.

Has any one have experience in building such forms ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video tutorials (my personal source of learning):

Nested form part 1: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 part 2: http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Formtastic part 1: http://railscasts.com/episodes/184-formtastic-part-1 part 2: http://railscasts.com/episodes/185-formtastic-part-2

In-place editing: http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing